# Do web camera's pass raw uncompressed video over USB?

Tags: video, camera, compression, rgb, yuv

Do web camera's pass raw uncompressed video over USB? Does anyone know what format the video is passed?
Thanks

Comment: Check this out - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question

Comment: That's why it is not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, most of the non high-end cameras have a built-in hardware ISP and no option to get the RAW. Thus, the image that gets out from the **hardware** is already JPEG/BMP. Webcams definitely fall into this category.

Comment: For many webcams, the data stream is YUV in some form (either interleaved or planar, with different chroma subsampling ratios). That's no more and no less common than (M)JPEG ones. Amongst hobby astronomers, the Phillips ToUCam webcam and derivates of it can be given a firmware update that makes the stream "true raw" (8-bit grey bayer patterned). As you've mentioned, "high-end" (anything for professional/commercial image processing use) tends to have the ability to deliver raw.